# Asp .net 4 mvc 2 Form Authentication Failure

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, cookies

I am developing an asp.net 4 mvc 2 web application that is a subsite of the main one.
for example the main website is
    www.example.com 
and the website that I am working on it is going to be 
    voip.example.com
when a user is typing voip.example.com if the user is not authenticated yet ,my website redirects them to 
    accounts.example.com
 where the login page is, and when they authenticate ,the main website create a cookie with name of 
    ExampleAuth
and a domain name of 
    .example.com
and expiration time is till 2015 and redirects to my website voip.example.com.

I am using AuthorizeAttribute form authentication on my website and when the AuthorizeCore method runs on my request that is redirected from main website the result of AuthorizeCore should be true.
On my PC with a win7 and IIS 7.5 it is working just fine but when I deploy it on a server that is windows server 2008 with IIS 7 or even in a windows server 2008 r2 with IIS 7.5 it seems that my web application couldnt access to the authentication cookie that is set by main website.

[image: a diagram of requests and their orders]

I think it is some kind of security configuration of IIS or windows server that cause this behaviour because I am using mvc's built in form authentication methods and everything nothing customized.

Recently I uploaded it on a server with windows Server 2008 r2 and IIS 7.5 and it worked but on my server with the same version of iis and windows it isnt working so I think it should be some kind of configuration or .... that cause this behavior.

does anyone know why this is happening ?

Comment: Start by checking the path set in the cookie on the server is what you expected - compare the properties to one set by your dev pc

Comment: the path is the same I checked couple of times '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a bug in asp.net mvc authentication and I solved it with installing
KB2656351 and KB963697 microsoft patches.